# Eigenvectors of an isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a linear isomorphism, with $n \geq 4$. I have to prove that $f$ and $f^{3}$ have the same eigenvectors.

Clearly, every eigenvector of $f$ is an eigenvector of $f^{3}$. For the converse, I think that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $f^{3}$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$ then $v$ is also a eigenvector of $f$ associated to the eigenvalue $\sqrt[3]{\lambda}$. But I am lost trying to prove this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DavidRaveh but multiplying that equation by $(f^{-1})^{3}$, using that $1/\lambda$ is an eigenvector of $(f^{-1})^{3}$, I just get $v = v$, so I think I am not seeing your argument

Comment: What about $f$ being for example a rotation of the plane of the first two components by $2\pi/3$? $f^3$ would have more eigenvectors than $f$.

Comment: Yes, just as @Matija posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to construct a counterexample is as follows.

Let $v_1, v_2, v_3,v_4$ be a basis of $R^4$. Define a linear map $T : R^4 \to R^4$ by $$Tv_1 = v_2\\ Tv_2 = v_3\\ Tv_3 = v_1\\Tv_4 = v_4$$ This is indeed an isomorphism as it is surjective and injective.

As you can see that $v_1$ is an eigenvector of $T^3$ with eigenvalue $1$. Whereas $T$ doesn’t have $v_1$ as an eigenvector.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=4$ and $f(v)=Av$, where $A$ is a rotation by 120° degrees in the first two coordinates, i.e.
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(2\pi/3) & \sin(2\pi/3) & 0 & 0\\-\sin(2\pi/3) & \cos(2\pi/3)&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
I'm pretty sure that $f$ has two eigenvectors, which are the third and fourth unit vector, while $f^3$ is the identity and thus has four eigenvectors, namely the unit vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. It must be that the statement in the exercise is incomplete.

Comment: I wondered if you maybe consider the matrix over the complex numbers, but it really doesn't seem that way. By the way, notice that the example canonically extends to arbitrary $n$ by preserving all unit vectors but the first two.